fillMaxWidth is not full max width of a screen inside LazyRow
Second row is using only fraction of a screen I want it to use full
But if I change Column width to e.g. 400.dp I can manipulate really good with width
I have LazyRow to scroll horizontally with modifier fillMaxWidth:
val list = remember { List(100) { it } }

LazyRow(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
) {
    items(list) {
        GameSite()
    }
}

Inside is this:
@Composable
fun GameSite() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp),
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Red)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Blue),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp),
            ) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}

I need two rows, one ontop the other.
I tried with fixed width in column and it works good but I want a dynamic width.

Please [edit] your question and provide an example that includes the LazyRow.

I fixed it with LazyRow

Your update made it a little bit more confusing so I edited it as I thought best. Please verify that this is still what you wanted to ask.

Its better yes :D

The problem with fillMaxWidth is that its result depends on what the parent provides as maximum constraints.
You say you want the second row to use the full width. But what is that actually, when it is eventually placed in a LazyRow?
A LazyRow provides a container that can hold much more content than can fit on the screen. It only displays what fits on the screen, but there is much more space available that can be reached by scrolling.
Although there is a technical limit to the width of a LazyRow's content it only displays the content that is at least partially scrolled into view. Since it doesn't even calculate anything that isn't scrolled into view, the virtual size of the LazyRow's content is unlimited.
Now, with this in mind, fillMaxWidth doesn't make any sense. Do you really want your item to fill up this unlimited amount of space (as stated above, technically it is limited)? But when the first item already takes up all available space, what about the other items?
You need to define a width for the items of a LazyRow that has an upper bound. fillMaxWidth has no upper bound so it won't work. If you do not want to provide a fixed width you can make it relative. If, for example, each item should take up the entire visible space of the LazyRow, you can use fillParentMaxWidth:
items(list) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()) {
        GameSite()
    }
}

fillParentMaxWidth has the view port of LazyRow as its upper bound so it will take up as much space as the (outer) size of the LazyRow. This is a special construct that is only available in the lambda of a LazyRow's item* function so you cannot use it inside of GameSite unless you make that composable an extension function of LazyItemScope.

This worked for me.
